# Add Text watermark in video in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to add a text watermark in a video which i am taking from my mobile application.
Currently I am using [FFmpeg Library](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) but it is throwing permission error (and I think its currently not maintained ) when I try to execute command  `ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {}`

This is how I am recoding video from app

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
launchTakeVideoActivity.launch(takeVideoIntent);

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launchTakeVideoActivity = 
registerForActivityResult(
new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
result -> {
 if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Intent data = result.getData();
    Uri url = data.getData();
    String videoUrl = Util.getPathFromURI( getApplicationContext(),url );
    String path = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID.mp4";
    String[] cmd = Util.createCommand(videoUrl,customerInfo,path);
    Util.waterMark( videoUrl,path,getApplicationContext(),cmd );
    Log.d("LOGCAT", "Video path is: " + videoUrl);
   }
} );
```

But Because in `Android 10` we cannot execute command inside private package which is `my.app.package/files` it is throwing permission error.
I have gone through couple of questions from `stackoverflow` but couldn't find the proper solution.
Anyone know how to solve this issue or anyother good free library to add watermark text on video

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using this library as it supports new android versions too, use the lts package if you want to support old versions too,

https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit

also you can save video in internal android package folder of your app, e.g. Android/data/yourapppacakge/  make a folder there and save it there